# Column types are wrong after df.read_pickle() (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [3]:
df = pd.read_pickle('uqt.pickle')
df.is_copy = False
df.dtypes

Out[3]:
query_date            object
channel               object
query                 object
email                 object
ymo           datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [6]:

df.iloc[1]['query_date']

Out[6]:
u'2013-01-02 04:28:02'
```

Is `object` just a shorthand for `u''` or dataframe actually knows that it has a (unicode) string?

`pandas==0.16.2`

Comment: strings and unicodes are referred to as `object` in pandas `DataFrames` and `Series`.

Comment: @Abdou turn it into an answer pls